# WebHook receives string data with + (plus) where whitespace should be

Tags: python, aws-lambda, twilio, aws-api-gateway, apache-velocity

My goal is to receive WhatsApp messages via API Gateway and store these in DynamoDB. I receive the data the following way through my webhook. My problem is that when `Body` should be saved as "Hello world" into the database. It is saved as "Hello+World". Do you have any idea how to avoid that behavior?

```
{'SmsMessageSid': 'SMb980630d616e300921cacc5d27835fb1', 'NumMedia': '0', 'SmsSid': 'SMb980630d616e300921cacc5d27835fb1', 'SmsStatus': 'received', 'Body': 'Test+131415+5%2B5%3D10', 'To': 'whatsapp%3A%2B4915734392273', 'NumSegments': '1', 'MessageSid': 'SMb980630d616e300921cacc5d27835fb1', 'AccountSid': 'AC358aa1d18557365a9e1f5e2ffcbcebe0', 'From': 'whatsapp%3A%2B4942357902', 'ApiVersion': '2010-04-01'}
```

When I print the received webhook, I already see `Body` formated the "wrong" way. I tried the following

```
messageBody = event.get('Body')
messageBody = unquote(messageBody)
```

But this only solved the part that `%2B` and `%3D` were now shown as

```
Test+131415+5+5=10
```

However, the + Between Test 131415 are still there.

I have the following Mapping Template in my API Gateway Integration Request (found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python-amazon-lambda#integrating-our-request-with-our-lambda-function)):

```
#set($httpPost = $input.path('$').split("&"))
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $httpPost )
 #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 #if( $kvTokenised.size() > 1 )
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : "$kvTokenised[1]"#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #else
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : ""#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
 #end
#end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) the solution: `urllib.parse.unquote_plus`